# echarts4r trigger action without using a button

Tags: echarts4r

Instead of [using a button](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/actions-buttons.html) to trigger and action in echarts4r, I'd like to trigger an action using a reactive.  I was thinking of creating an invisible button and programmatically having it clicked, but this seems like an extremely inelegant solution.